# Angular2 effective way to reuse form component for validation

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

Consider the following form with some validator for input field

```
<form #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="userName">User Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.name" name="name" id="userName" required  minlength="4" maxlength="24" #name="ngModel">
            <div *ngIf="name.errors && (name.dirty || name.touched)"    class="alert alert-danger">
                <div [hidden]="!name.errors.required">
                    Name is required
                </div>
                <div [hidden]="!name.errors.minlength">
                    Name must be at least 4 characters long.
                </div>
                <div [hidden]="!name.errors.maxlength">
                    Name cannot be more than 24 characters long.
                </div>
         </div>
     </div>
<button type="button" pButton icon="fa-check" 
      (click)="saveUser()" label="Save" [disabled]="!userForm.form.valid"></button>
</form>
```

Here the validation messages are working fine. The same control is being used in many pages for `Name` field, adding such validator message like the above is making my templates larger and duplicates the code.

If I have another input field to get `Department name (Min:6 chars & Max:30 chars)` in same/ different form, I supposed to write error message div part again.

Is there any generalized way to write a Input component once by specifing Required,Min,Max & pattern explicitely and use it in many places.

Comment: Use a component that's get input form control and show the errors

Comment: i went though [Angular 2 Form Builder and Validation Management](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-form-builder-and-validation-management). here it often scanned  and keep on querying validation services. It might affect performance.